# Call method overridden in child class, from the parent class [PHP -> JS]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, overriding, prototypal-inheritance

In my **Javascript** there is a parent *Base* class that will be extended by others.

I'd like to:

- define in it a method *getSubject()* that could be common to all children, when it is not overridden.
- make *getSubject()* rely on a *Base* property, that eventually could be overridden as well.
- always call the *getSubject()* method in the context of the *caller* (the children classes or the *Base* class)

To clarify (hopefully) what I want to do..

#### I wrote (non-valid) *PHP* code as an example.

```php
<?php

class Base
{
    const SUBJ_SELECTOR = 'input';

    public function init()
    {
        $this->wrapper = ....;
        $this->subject = $this->getSubj();
        if ($this->subject.attr('data-active')) {
            // ... do stuff
        }
    }

    public function getSubj()       // One definition in parent
    {
        return $this->wrapper.find(self::SUBJ_SELECTOR);
    }
}

class Select extends Base
{
    const SUBJ_SELECTOR = 'select'      // Override just the selector
}

class Textarea extends Base
{
    const SUBJ_SELECTOR = 'textarea[name=foo]';

    public function getSubj()       // Eventual overriding
    {
        $subjs = $this->wrapper.find(self::SUBJ_SELECTOR);
        foreach ($subjs as $subj) {
            if ($subj.attr('multiline')) {
                return $subj;
            }
        }

        return $subjs;
    }
}
```

#### I'd like to achieve the same result with *Javascript* (and *JQuery* eventually).

Actually I wrote some code (that I still didn't test) as a sketch:

```
var Base = function() {
    this.options = {};

    this.subject_selector = 'input';
    this.wrapper = $('.container');
};


Base.prototype.getSubject = function() {
    return this.wrapper.find(this.subject_selector);
}

Base.prototype.init = function() {
    subj = this.getSubject();
    if(subj.attr('data-active')) {
        // ... do stuff
    }
}

var Select = function() {
    this.subject_selector = 'select';
}

Select.prototype = new Base();
Select.prototype.constructor = Select;

var Textarea = function() {
    this.subject_selector = 'textarea';
}

Textarea.prototype.getSubject = function() {
    subjs = this.wrapper.find(this.subject_selector);
    for (var i = subjs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(subjs[i].attr('multiline')) {
            return subjs[i];
        }
    };
    return subjs;
}

Textarea.prototype = new Base();
Textarea.prototype.constructor = Textarea;
```

Would it work correctly? Is this a proper use of the inheritance model?

### Am I callling the method in the right way and will I get the expected result when executing the *init()* method?

Comment: Isn't the prototype supposed to be defined outside the base function? Try putting `Base.prototype...` outside of `var Base = function() {`, because `Base` isn't defined inside `Base` (`Base.Base` is undefined, see what I mean?) See http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp

Comment: You shouldn't edit your original question with the solution I suggested, because now my first comment is irrelevant. And the syntax should be : `Base.prototype.getSubject = function() {...`

Comment: Yeah, I'm not so much into JS, and even less into inheritance. Cause of that I'm asking. Anyway I changed the code and put `Base` (and `Textarea`) out. Don't know if it is completely valid but should be enough to understand the problem and give some addressing about it.
Maybe we should delete both the comments when they become irrelevant.

Comment: The thing is, they _shouldn't_ become irrelevant :) Leave your original question intact, so other people can get in, read it and suggest other options.

Comment: you can use the underscore's extend functionality which will be really helpful for you. http://underscorejs.org/#extend, it gives a handy tool in such cases. But the catch is you should use the _.extend when inheriting.

Comment: @allupaku thanks for the suggestion. I actually have *lodash* available, not *underscore*. But I'd like to see a *Javascript*-only solution (eventually *JQuery*).